# How to parse Json Array from REST post request

Tags: java, arrays, json, java-8, java-ee-8

how can I parse JSON array to list with objects. Client from another system from which I call request is consuming in body JSON and returning in response

```
List<Model1>
```

as JSON. When I call this request I want to get this response and convert it to List (which is in my system). I know the structure of objects included in list, so I prepared POJO class to parse model1 into model2. Do I need to wrap my Model2 class (POJO in my system) to another class?

I'm using WebTarget, URL is completed and it looks like this:

```
WebTarget wt = target();

 wt.path(URL)
.request()
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.post(Entity.entity(consumedBody,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Model2);
```

Or should I use wrapped class that contains one field with List, let's call this WrapperModel2

```
 wt.path(URL)
.request()
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.post(Entity.entity(consumedBody,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), WrapperModel2);
```

Each time I got error that says "Couldnt parse JSON Array into: Model2 or WrapperModel2. What's the way to correctly parse Json Array into List of specific objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using JAX-RS, So could you please try this :

```
.post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), new GenericType<List<Model2>>() {
        });
```